# Custom collection view layout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

How can I achieve this layout:

[image]

The content flows like the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` with `UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal`, but there can be more than one section depending on collection view size. Also, the sections don't occupy full height

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about promoting a Cocoapod released by the author of the question.

Comment: @Fogmeister my bad I didn't get an answer so I wrote my own component. You can compare the dates for the commits. A moderator can delete the question

Comment: We did create the pod after we couldn't find the answer anywhere, I've posted the link so if anyone has same problem, he can actually get a proper answer, and not "use html" jibberish.

Comment: OPK, retracted close vote. I hadn't looked at the dates. Thought you had asked and answered in order to get the repo on here :D Good work on answering your own question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this pod could help you ;)

https://github.com/thomasjoulin/TJCollectionViewColumnFlowLayout